# How to clear the background of just the current page?

Tags: backgrounds, eso-pic

[`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) provides `\AddToShipoutPictureBG` to add content to the background at every page and `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` to add it only to the current page. `\ClearShipoutPicture` clears all the content. But there is no `\ClearShipoutPicture*` to clear the content only for the current page.

I would like to show some content in every page but chapter pages. Using `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{}` when the chapter is created doesn't work, since the previous content is not cleared, it is just added. If I use `\ClearShipoutPicture` I need to know when the page is changed to add the content again. How should I do this?

I also tried [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background), but `\NoBgThispage` is [not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175198/avoid-background-to-be-shown-in-toc-and-chapter-page). I could use

```
\backgroundsetup{contents={
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  ...
 \end{tikzpicture}
,angle=0
}}
```

instead of `\AddToShipoutPictureBG{...}` and `\backgroundsetup{contents={}}` instead of `\ClearShipoutPicture`. The results is pretty much the same.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch1.tex}
\lipsum[1-3]\section{First section ch1}\lipsum[4-10]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch2.tex}
\lipsum[11-14]\section{First section ch2}\lipsum[15-25]
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\regtotcounter{sidecnt} \newcounter{sidecnt}

\colorlet{sidecolor}{red!75}
\colorlet{sidelabelcolor}{blue}

\def\vsidemargin{3.5cm}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\pheight}{(\paperheight-2*\vsidemargin)/28.453}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myt}{-(\vsidemargin/28.453)-(\thesidecnt-1)/\totvalue{sidecnt}*\pheight}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{-(\vsidemargin/28.453)-\thesidecnt/\totvalue{sidecnt}*\pheight}
 \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\def\corner{east}\def\sign{-}}{\def\corner{west}\def\sign{+}}
 \fill[sidecolor] ($(current page.north \corner)+(0,\myt)$) rectangle ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.75,\myb)$);
 \node[font=\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries] at ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.375,\myt-0.5)$) {\color{sidelabelcolor}\thechapter};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\importchapter[2]{
 \chapter{#1}
 \stepcounter{sidecnt}
 %\ClearShipoutPicture* alike
 \input{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\importchapter{First chapter}{ch1.tex}
\importchapter{Second chapter}{ch2.tex}

\end{document}
```

I don't want the background to be shown in pages 1 and 5.

Comment: Did you try the method explained in [Gonzalo Medina's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175208/)? There is a comment from the user there explaining that the method worked for them. If not, please provide a Minimum (non-)Working Example. If Gonzalo Medina is around, I am sure he will then be happy to help you. (And, if not, likely somebody else will be able to. But it is his package, after all.)

Comment: OK. He was last seen almost a month ago. But I'm sure somebody will be able to help once you post some code.

Comment: I checked Gonzalo Medina's answer, and commented there at first. But, since I saw that he has been out for a month I tried with `eso-pic` and then thought it would be better to open a new question. The difference between that question and this is that I'm actually using `\input` to get a new chapter, and I don't want to modify its content. I provided a MWE and added some details.

Comment: In that case, I recommend cheating ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cheat by adding a white rectangle the size of the page to the background on chapter pages to cover over the background picture rather than actually clearing it. Obviously, if you are printing on any colour of paper other than white, you'd need to match the colour. But hopefully that is not so and this will work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch1.tex}
  \lipsum[1-3]\section{First section ch1}\lipsum[4-10]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch2.tex}
  \lipsum[11-14]\section{First section ch2}\lipsum[15-25]
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\regtotcounter{sidecnt} \newcounter{sidecnt}

\colorlet{sidecolor}{red!75}
\colorlet{sidelabelcolor}{blue}

\def\vsidemargin{3.5cm}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pheight}{(\paperheight-2*\vsidemargin)/28.453}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myt}{-(\vsidemargin/28.453)-(\thesidecnt-1)/\totvalue{sidecnt}*\pheight}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{-(\vsidemargin/28.453)-\thesidecnt/\totvalue{sidecnt}*\pheight}
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\def\corner{east}\def\sign{-}}{\def\corner{west}\def\sign{+}}
    \fill[sidecolor] ($(current page.north \corner)+(0,\myt)$) rectangle ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.75,\myb)$);
    \node[font=\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries] at ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.375,\myt-0.5)$) {\color{sidelabelcolor}\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand\importchapter[2]{
  \chapter{#1}
  \stepcounter{sidecnt}
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,color=white]
      \fill (current page.north east) rectangle (current page.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  \input{#2}}

\begin{document}

  \importchapter{First chapter}{ch1.tex}
  \importchapter{Second chapter}{ch2.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image: Cheat by covering over the background on some pages]

Comment: I was going mad trying to cheat with `\newtoggle`s seen [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52746/include-chapters-in-list-of-figures-with-titletoc) to get to the same point :S. Thanks for that easier way. I won't tell anyone you recommended cheating ;). Hope Gonzalo will find how to fix it in future versions.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I came to, using a `\newtoggle` provided by the `etoolbox` package. The one provided by @cfr is straightforward and uses the commands provided by the `eso-pic` package, which is already used. However, this solution covers only the desired part, maintaining any other content which may be in the background. I though it would be good to have both answers published.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch1.tex}
\lipsum[1-3]\section{First section ch1}\lipsum[4-10]
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ch2.tex}
\lipsum[11-14]\section{First section ch2}\lipsum[15-25]
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{etoolbox} %added
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz,bm}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\regtotcounter{sidecnt} \newcounter{sidecnt}

\colorlet{sidecolor}{red!75}
\colorlet{sidelabelcolor}{blue}

\def\vsidemargin{3.5cm}

\newtoggle{noSide} %added

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\pheight}{(\paperheight-2*\vsidemargin)/28.453}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myt}{-(\vsidemargin/28.453)-(\thesidecnt-1)/\totvalue{sidecnt}*\pheight}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\myb}{-(\vsidemargin/28.453)-\thesidecnt/\totvalue{sidecnt}*\pheight}
 \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}{\def\corner{east}\def\sign{-}}{\def\corner{west}\def\sign{+}}
 \fill[sidecolor] ($(current page.north \corner)+(0,\myt)$) rectangle ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.75,\myb)$);
 \node[font=\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries] at ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.375,\myt-0.5)$) {\color{sidelabelcolor}\thechapter};
 \iftoggle{noSide}{ \fill[white] ($(current page.north \corner)+(0,\myt)$) rectangle ($(current page.north \corner)+(\sign0.75,\myb)$); }{} %added
\end{tikzpicture}
\global\togglefalse{noSide} %added
}

\newcommand\importchapter[2]{
 \chapter{#1}
 \toggletrue{noSide} %added
 \stepcounter{sidecnt}
 %\ClearShipoutPicture* alike
 \input{#2}
}

\begin{document}

\importchapter{First chapter}{ch1.tex}
\importchapter{Second chapter}{ch2.tex}

\end{document}
```