# Table of contents design with images/background

Tags: table-of-contents, book-design

I would like to place, just in the contents, a background image left-aligned, like this example and leave the page number closer to the chapter name: one aligned to the right, the other to the left, from the center.

I found something on the forum here, but it wouldn't be what I'm looking for:

[image: example]

...

I found this solution:

[Formatting Multi-Page Table of Contents with Background Images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370562/formatting-multi-page-table-of-contents-with-background-images)

But it's not quite the design I'm looking for.

I need help, please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

$ Preamble:

```
% remove header in table of contents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

$ Configuration Table of Contents:

```
    \backgroundsetup{
    placement = center,
    contents = {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{frame-contents.png}},
    scale = 1, % 15 is default for placement "center"
    angle = 0, % 60 is default for placement "center"
    opacity = 100,
    }

\begin{tabular}{cp{4.5cm}p{5cm}}
 &  & \renewcommand\contentsname{Sumário} % Rename 'Contents'
\small{\tableofcontents}
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\else
  \thispagestyle{empty}
\fi\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here, and by itself it certainly does not reproduce the design above.